# How can I dynamically add an attribute to each option tag generated by sfWidgetFormPropelChoice?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

In my symfony 1.4 application, I'm generating a select drop down as part of a form.

I later want to apply some jQuery (ddSlick) to that select to re-style it.   In order to do so, I need to add an attribute to each option tag.

So for example, I'd like my select to generate:

```
<select id="demo-htmlselect">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?  Perhaps with an alternate or extended widget?

Comment: Isn't the almost same question than [your other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423854/how-can-i-add-descriptions-to-the-options-in-an-html-select-box) ?

Comment: The other one was meant to be a more generic case, although i accidentally tagged it as symfony.

Comment: You unaccept because it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize the select render, you should extend the default widget and made your own render.

So, create this file for exemple: `/lib/widget/myWidgetFormSelect.class.php` with:

```
class myWidgetFormSelect extends sfWidgetFormSelect
{
  protected function getOptionsForSelect($value, $choices)
  {
    $mainAttributes = $this->attributes;
    $this->attributes = array();

    if (!is_array($value))
    {
      $value = array($value);
    }

    $value_set = array();
    foreach ($value as $v)
    {
      $value_set[strval($v)] = true;
    }

    $options = array();
    foreach ($choices as $key => $option)
    {
      $attributes = array(
        'value'            => self::escapeOnce($key),
        'data-imagesrc'    => self::escapeOnce($option['imagesrc']),
        'data-description' => self::escapeOnce($option['description'])
      );
      if (isset($value_set[strval($key)]))
      {
        $attributes['selected'] = 'selected';
      }

      $options[] = $this->renderContentTag('option', self::escapeOnce($option['title']), $attributes);
    }

    $this->attributes = $mainAttributes;

    return $options;
  }
}
```

Then, you should trick the way you gave the `$choices` to the widget. Here, the widget wait for an array like that:

```
$choices = array(
  0 => array(
    'title'       => 'Facebook',
    'imagesrc'    => 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png',
    'description' => 'Description with Facebook',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'title'       => 'Twitter',
    'imagesrc'    => 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png',
    'description' => 'Description with Twitter',
  ),
);
```